# Can I detect hibernate not found annotation work

Tags: spring, hibernate, annotations, many-to-one

I have two objects with a Many-to-One relationship:

Object 1:

```
@Entity
@Table(name=”Person”)
public class Person {
    Long id;
    String name;
    String surname;
    … // other fields

    @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "groupId")
    Group group;

    ....all the getters and setters…
}
```

Object 2:

```
public class Group {
    @Id
    @Column
    Long groupId;

    @Column
    protected String groupName;

    @Column(precision = 15, scale = 0)
    protected long exampleFieldId;

    ...rest of code....
}
```

Field “group” in class Person can be null. How can I determine where the null value is obtained from the database or from the "NotFound" annotation?

This situation could be in the following case: the user at the database level has access to a limited set of groups.

Answer (score 0):

'Not found' is the same as null in this case. You can't init group with null because you will get NullPointerException.

Comment: Not certainly in that way. The group in Person can be null. In fact, Group is a View. And for some reason it may not contain some of the values of the base table. We get a situation when a person refers to a nonexistent group. I want not only to fill field group in Person by null but display to the operator that he does not have access rights to this value of Group.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace @NotFound by below getter and debug when it catches ObjectNotFoundException, but if your group is already null i think hibernate may initialize group object with null which may lead to NPE, but you can debug using this code instead of using annotation @NotFound if you want some custom loading behavior of hibernate proxies.

```
@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "groupId")
Group group;

private Group getGroup(){
   if(!Hibernate.isInitialized(group)) {
        try {
             Hibernate.initialize(group);
        } catch(org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException e) {
            group = null;
        }
    }
  return group;
}
```

Comment: I have this error:
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find com.test.datamodel.mappings.Group with id 123; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.test.datamodel.mappings.Group with id 123

Comment: I've tried to follow your approach, but even if I check the object with Hibernate.isInitialized(), it says in fact *it's initialized* even if it's not found. So still the only way I have to control this behaviour somehow is to catch for the NPE exception when I try to access some property from the null object, which is not the smartest way. But I have no idea how to check for the existance of the object itself, not its "inicialization".